# How to enable disable component in a complex vue app?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am just new to vue and working on this example Notes application, it can be found below

https://coligo.io/learn-vuex-by-building-notes-app/

My question is how can I change component seen on screen right behind the toolbar. I have read basic guide but I am still behind it.

Lets say I have a button on left side call it message and have another component listing like NotesList and its called MessagesList. So, When I click message button, I want NotesList dissappear and MessageList come instead of that, and vice versa. I do not want NotesList stay as consistent on screen.

Here is App.vue and main.js files, please look in github page for mode code.
https://github.com/coligo-io/notes-app-vuejs-vuex

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <toolbar></toolbar>
    <notes-list></notes-list>
    <editor></editor>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Toolbar from './Toolbar.vue'
import NotesList from './NotesList.vue'
import Editor from './Editor.vue'
import MessageList from './MessageList.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    Toolbar,
    NotesList,
    Editor,
    MessageList
  }
}
</script>
```

Main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import store from './vuex/store'
import App from './components/App.vue'

new Vue({
  store, // inject store to all children
  el: 'body',
  components: { App }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this either by using [`v-if`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if) on each of the components, or by using [dynamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components). In either case, your button should toggle a data value which would be used to control which component is displayed.

Comment: I see some examples such as this link but how can I apply in this Notes App. Should I put a v-if for top div ?? https://paulund.co.uk/vuejs-conditional-show-and-hide

Comment: I see Dynamic-Components is best choice for that but otes app is built in vue 1.0 and I think Dynamic-Components example is 2.0 How can I upgrade that Notas App to 2.0 without pain ?

Comment: Vue 1 also has [dynamic components](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components).

Comment: Lets say I use v-if="seen" but in the example I just post v-if and v-on are on same html, so how can I do on different components ? I mean a button in one component will show hide another component, is that possible ? Arguments in html are global ?

Comment: And all examples I see there is data: { seen: true }. However there is no data instead App component which imports other components. you can check code in Notes App its very few lines of code.

Comment: Thanks for  information. Vue 1 may have dynamic components but I do not not change structure so much, I just want to change component or change page s a classic application.